# mpi4py: Spawning processes and parent not exiting, hangs execution on call to comm.Disconnect

Tags: python-3.x, openmpi, spawn, mpi4py

I am testing a code that needs matrix multiplication, and I want to delegate this operation to another code that I modified from the examples in mpi4py for matrix multiplication. The code that spawns to this script is:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import sys

A = np.array([[1., 2.], [4., 5.], [7., 8.], [3., 6]])
B = np.array([[9., 8., 7.], [6., 5., 4.]])
C = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))
comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable, args=['libraries/multiplication.py', str(A.shape[0]), str(A.shape[1]), str(B.shape[1])], maxprocs=3)
comm.Send(A, dest=0)
comm.Bcast(B, root=MPI.ROOT)
comm.Recv(C, source=0)
print(C)
comm.Disconnect()
```

The code prints the matrix product and is correct, doesn't show any error message, but doesn't exit. I am calling `Disconnect` on multiplication.py on the parent communicator only. I am running with `mpirun -n 1 python test.py`

If I ran the computing PI example on https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html, I am also getting the hanging situation.
I am on Ubuntu 16.04.6, have openmpi version 1.10.2.

Comment: It may be related to your environment, for instance a too old version of OpenMpi. You could try to install mpi4py using anaconda and the conda-forge channel. You will get a recent mpi implementation, either mpich or openmpi.